# BufferBlock.ReceiveAsync(timeout) hang but BufferBlock.ReceiveAsync() works OK

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Either I am doing something really wrong, but the below never returns it hangs forever on the `ReceiveAsync` despite specifying a 1 second timeout.

I would expect it to return null value, after the time out.

```
/* snipped MyContainer class */

private readonly BufferBlock<byte[]> queue = new BufferBlock<byte[]>();

public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
     // makes no difference if creating with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
     await Task
            .Factory
            .StartNew(async () =>
            {

              while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
              {                     
                 // we get here OK, but no further if i use TimeSpan for delay
                 // without Timespan i.e. ReceiveAsync() only, it does **not** hang
                 var item = await 
                             this
                               .queue
                               .ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

                      // process it, but we never get here we sleep forever
                      await ProcessAsync(item);
                    }
             } /*,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning*/);

     // we get here and print the below OK
     Console.WriteLine("thread created and running");
}

// this is called by the original (or some other) thread
// either if i call this or not, the above thread code still locks on ReceiveAsync
public void Add(byte[] data)
{
   Console.WriteLine("adding");
   this.queue.Post(data);
   Console.WriteLine("done"); // gets posted OK     
}
```

**Important update - works OK if I do not specify a delay**

```
var item = await this.queue.ReceiveAsync());
```

The code works OK if I remove the delay, however I do some background housekeeping every second (for packet counters etc) so this is important to wake up if nothing received within 1 second.

**Other notes:**

I am calling the above code from a generic dot net worker host:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MyContainer containerClass;
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> logger;

    public Worker(MyContainer containerClass, ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        this.containerClass = containerClass;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        this.containerClass.ExecuteAsync(stoppingToken);

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {                
            this.logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is called after the worker is built by `IHostBuilder` and I called `Host.Run()`.

My understanding is (which I clearly need to work on!) since I create the thread, it should run totally independently from (and not block on) the thread that created/called it... in other words it should be able to call ReceiveAsync within the thread itself without getting blocked.

Comment: Did you call `.Result` or `.Wait` somewhere?

Comment: Are you blocking (i.e., using `Wait` or `Result`) anywhere further up your call stack?

Comment: Thanks have updated my code to include the thread start code

Comment: Where do you call the `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: @g18c by looking at the documentation it seems that ReceiveAsync returns a cancelled task whenever the timeout fires. So, the task you are awaiting is canceled and the await operation should throw an OperationCanceledException. Have you tried to run your code in the VS debugger and to ask the debugger to break on each exception ? Just to be sure that your hosted service is still running after the timeout fires

Comment: @g18c My suspicious is that your code in the version using the timeout throws an exception which is not handled by anyone and stops the background task aimed to dequeu the items. So, your feeling is that the code is awaiting indefinitely but in reality there is no one to dequeu the items that your are posting.

Comment: Yes you are right! I am catching that exception now. I haven't a clue why it isn't showing up as unhandled by visual studio. Will do some more digging

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_DataflowBlock_ReceiveAsync__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_ISourceBlock___0__System_TimeSpan_)

Comment: @g18c becaue you probably need to ask the VS debugger to break on each CLR exception. You need to do that from the debugger -> options window in VS.

Comment: @g18c after investigating your issue and gained a full understand of it, please remember to update your question with a final explanation of the issue, so that each casual reader can get a full understanding of the problem. Lots of users probably skips over comments and just read the question.

Comment: @EnricoMassone have done so with an answer, feel free to copy/paste from your account and I will award to you. Thanks everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` with an async delegate creates a nested task:

```
Task<Task> nestedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { //...
```

You are awaiting the outer task, but not the inner, so the inner task becomes a fire-and-forget task. It is possible to await both tasks in one line by using the `await` operator twice:

```
await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { //...
```

Alternatively you can combine the two tasks in one by using the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) method.

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { /* ... */ }).Unwrap();
```

...or even better use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method instead of the `Task.Factory.StartNew`, because the former understands async delegates, and does the unwrapping for you:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { //...
```

If you are interested about the differences between `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run`, you could read an informative article [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: Great stuff, will get that changed can see how that would cause an issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who responded and finally to Enrico (feel free to copy/paste and i will assign the answer to you) the code was actually running OK.

A TimeoutException exception was being thrown, but wasn't caught by my code or Visual Studio.

Enabling all CLR exceptions as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019 the exception started being thrown.

I then handled the exception within code, and was able to proceed as my design required:

```
public Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    return Task
            .Factory
            .StartNew(async () => {

                while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(UpdateFrequencySeconds);
                        var item = await this.queue.ReceiveAsync(ts);
                        await ProcessAsync(item);
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException)
                    {
                        // this is ok, timer expired 
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        this.logger.LogError(e.ToString());
                    }

                    UpdateCounters();
                }

                await StopAsync();
              },
              stoppingToken,
              TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
              TaskScheduler.Default)
              .Unwrap();
 }
```