# Event based Task framework for C# completing before process complete

Tags: c#, events, async-await, task

I am trying to create a system that processes events as they come in as separate Tasks. This is all inside a Windows Service application that runs until it is stopped, and when stopped, waits until all Tasks complete before stopping.

I have the following, simplified, code:

```
IList<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();//this is a private class variable.

private void Event_Fired(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    StartTask();
}

private void StartTask(){
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await process.ProcessEvent(true, StoppingToken));
   _tasks.Add(task);
}

private void MonitorTasks(){
    for (int i = _tasks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Task aTask = _laneTasks[i];
        if (aTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            _tasks.Remove(aTask);
            Log.Information($"Task {aTask.Id} completed.");
        }
    }
}

public async Task ProcessEvent(){
    //do some async processing
    await Task.Delay(5000); //if I add a delay before returning the Task, it is completed prior to this delay.
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the Task is **completing** before **ProcessEvent** has completed. I need to ensure the tasks are completed before allowing the process to stop.

The process also has to allow new events to enter and spawn new Tasks at anytime.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: starting task just to start a task is super confusing... Consider not doing that.

Comment: What Alexei is getting at is that you can do this: `Task task = process.ProcessEvent();` (notice no `await`)

Comment: Also, which task is completing before `ProcessEvent`? And how did you determine that?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the idea is to start tasks so that the events can be processed asynchronously no matter when they come in. I'm not sure what you mean by just starting one to start one?

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks. I tried that too. Also, the Task that starts ProcessEvent is completing before it returns. I thought the task would only complete when the method is runs returns.

Comment: It's kind of hard to put in words... Grab your favorite rubber duck and explain it the `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await ...` line of code (read documentation first). In particular pay attention to what happens with inner task... and maybe read on "what it means hot vs. cold task in C#".

Comment: *"the Task that starts ProcessEvent is completing before it returns"* - How do you know that?

Comment: @GabrielLuci a breakpoint

Comment: What did you do at the breakpoint?

Comment: @GabrielLuci remove the task from the list. The list keeps track of all currently running tasks so I can wait until they are all processed before stopping the service. The service waits for a CancellationToken to be cancelled, checks to see if any tasks are still running, and if any are, loops with a delay to wait until they are all done.  i.e. the list is empty.

Comment: Here is an older answer to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425513/bufferblock-receiveasynctimeout-hang-but-bufferblock-receiveasync-works-ok/61434745#61434745).

Comment: Bottom line: [`StartNew` is a dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). If you want to send work to the thread pool, use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` creates a new `Task` that executes the supplied delegate. The concrete type of the returned `Task` will depend on the return type of the delegate.

So let's look at the delegate you're passing in:

```
async () => await process.ProcessEvent(true, StoppingToken)
```

OK, that's a `Func<Task>`. Invoking the function will create a new `Task` and return it. So your `Task<Task>` completes immediately, with the `Result` value set to the inner `Task` object.

To complicate matters a little further, `ProcessEvent()` itself creates a `Task` that is, ultimately, what you want to wait on. So you're creating a `Task` to create a `Task` to wait on a `Task`. Of course the outer-most `Task` finishes as soon as the waiter `Task` is created, since its job is now *done*.

Since your code already does manual waiting across a collection of `Task` objects, you don't need a `Task` whose whole purpose is to wait for the innermost `Task` to complete. And since you're already returning a `Task` from `ProcessEvent()` you don't need a `Task` to create a `Task`.

Do this instead:

```
_tasks.Add(ProcessEvent());
```

Comment: Ah yes I see what I'm doing wrong now. If I just go Task task = ProcessEvent() it works. Thanks. That was the fundamental part I was getting wrong. ProcessEvent returns a task already. I then need to call Start() myself. Task.Run seems to work too.

Comment: However, keep in mind that `ProcessEvent()` will not return until it hits the first `await`. You might still want to use `await Task.Yield()` or `Task.Run`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks. It doesn't do much anyway so returns very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your problem:

```cs
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await process.ProcessEvent(true, StoppingToken));
```

This spins up a new Task, which completes immediately. Try running the Task instead.

```cs
Task task = Task.Run(() => process.ProcessEvent(true, StoppingToken));
```

Comment: Won't work. Calling `ProcessEvent` creates a `Task`. All he'd be waiting on is that construction step completing, not the full run of the `ProcessEvent` code.

Comment: @Corey actually the `Task.Run` method understands async delegates, and unwraps automatically nested `Task<Task>`s, unlike the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method. You can read more about this [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: So `Task.Run()` does a lot of work that we can avoid by just capturing the `Task` created by calling `ProcessEent`.